# Filtering Data in ASp.net Core using EFCore

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ef-core-5.0

i do have a web api project which using asp.net core and SQL Server and EFCore5 . i have an entity model for patient which has a diagnosticID column and i want to filter the patients based on this column Id ( GUID ) , how can i implement this scenario :
1- when the client does not send any diagnosticId ( null ) , i want to return all the patients .
2- when the client send the specific diagnosticId , i need to have the patients which has this specific diagnosticId .

basically , null has to translate All and the rest translate to the sent Id . i can implement this with If and Else like this

```
    If(diagnosticId == null ) 
    { 
    //Query to return all the patients 
    } else {
    //Query to return patients with specific Id 
    }
```

but i think there should be a better and more professional way of doing this .
can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ is composable. You could do it like this to avoid repeating the base query:

```csharp
var query = context.Patients;

if (diagnosticId != null)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.DiagnosticId == diagnosticId);
}
```